# How to replace in place a string in binary files with bash

Tags: python, bash

I want to rename all files' extension in several zip files. Replacing .xxx into .yyy in hex mode works most of the time since there is 1 in 2^32 chance that I replace the wrong binary data.

But how should I do that with bash in Linux? BBE doesn't seem to replace in place as sed does, which leads to creating temporary files.

**Edit**:
I wrote a bash script but it wouldn't work due to failure to create files in `./tmp` in `termux`. It should have listed files contained, translated to `zipnote` command format and renamed several names in one go:

```bash
# There is no /tmp dir in termux. A local temp folder is created
mkdir tmp
zipinfo -1 $1 |ack .pdg |while read n; 
    do echo @ $n; 
    echo @=${n%.pdg}.png; 
    echo '@ (zip file comment below this line)'; 
done | zipnote -w -b ./tmp $1
```

Error was:

```
zipnote error: Bad file descriptor
zipnote error: Temporary file failure
```

**Edit**: I wrote a piece of python script (see answer below).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255259/discussion-on-question-by-schezuk-how-to-replace-in-place-a-string-in-binary-fil); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the brief `.zip` format spec on Wiki, I wrote myself a dirty piece of python script and it worked.
I have moved it from the question to the answer here. It shall replace a file name's last three characters with a string in equal byte count.

```py
import sys
from struct import *

encoding='utf-8'
ansi_enc='gbk'
pattern_1=b'pdg'
pattern_2=b'PDG'
replacement=b'png'
with open(sys.argv[1],"r+b") as f:
    while True:
        i=f.tell()
        head = f.read(4)
        if head==b'PK\x03\x04':
            f.seek(i+18)
            cl, ul, fnl, exl = unpack('<LLHH', f.read(12))
            f.seek(i+30)
            name = f.read(fnl)
            try:
                print (name.decode(encoding))
            except Exception as e:
                if encoding=='utf-8':
                    encoding=ansi_enc
                    f.seek(i)
                    continue
                else:
                    f.close()
                    break
            else:
                if name[-3:]==pattern_1 or name[-3:]==pattern_2:
                    f.seek(i+30)
                    f.write(name[:-3])
                    f.write(replacement)
                f.seek(i+30+fnl+exl+cl)
        elif head==b'PK\x01\x02':
            f.seek(i+28)
            fnl, exl, fcl = unpack('<HHH', f.read(6))
            f.seek(i+46)
            name = f.read(fnl)
            print (name.decode(encoding))
            if name[-3:]==pattern_1 or name[-3:]==pattern_2:
                f.seek(i+46)
                f.write(name[:-3])
                f.write(replacement)
            f.seek(i+46+fnl+exl+fcl)
        elif head==b'PK\x05\x06':
            f.close()
            print('done')
            break
        else:#try to search next valid signature
            f.seek(i+1)#Get a byte, get a byte, get a byte, byte, byte
            continue
```

However, along with many other issues, the script hasn't covered signatures like `PK\x07\x08` which has been encountered. It seems related with split archive or data descriptor. See below,

[image]

```
3E 42 12 0E A5 54 56 AF  F6 9F 04 55 B6 C0 01 FB  50 4B 07 08 1C 1A 04 AB  AD 5E 02 00 91 5E 02 00 
50 4B 03 04 0A 00 09 00  63 00 76 BB 73 4E 8D 94  9E BB D6 8B 02 00 BA 8B  02 00 2B 00 48 00 31 34 
31 36 34 34 37 35 5F C6  FB B3 B5 BB FA D0 B5 BB  F9 B4 A1 CF B0 CC E2 B2  E1 5F 70 31 32 37 2F 30 
30 30 30 30 31 2E 70 64  67 01 99 07 00 01 00 41  45 03 00 00 75 70 39 00  01 42 A7 29 86 31 34 31 
36 34 34 37 35 5F E6 B1  BD E8 BD A6 E6 9C BA E6  A2 B0 E5 9F BA E7 A1 80  E4 B9 A0 E9 A2 98 E5 86 
8C 5F 70 31 32 37 2F 30  30 30 30 30 31 2E 70 64  67 D6 DE DD F5 AC 5F 04  18 06 1B B0 88 AD AB 1F
```

A error-prone strategy is that just move on to the next point and retry, which may risk damaging data afterwards.

The official specification link:
https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT